# Magento - Difference between validator and validator.validate()

Tags: magento-1.9, php, javascript

In the login.phtml, what is the difference between validator and validate - Could someone explain what is the meaning of each of the lines below.

```
function onepageLogin(button)
        {
            if(loginForm.validator && loginForm.validator.validate()){
                button.disabled = true;
                loginForm.submit();
            }
        }
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at js/prototype/validation.js

```
.....
onSubmit :  function(ev){
    if(!this.validate()) Event.stop(ev);
},
validate : function() {
    var result = false;
    var useTitles = this.options.useTitles;
    var callback = this.options.onElementValidate;
...
```

Then take a look at js/mage/adminhtml/form.js or (/js/varien/form.js)

```
varienForm.prototype = {
    initialize : function(formId, validationUrl){
        this.formId = formId;
        this.validationUrl = validationUrl;
        this.submitUrl = false;

        if($(this.formId)){
            this.validator  = new Validation(this.formId, {onElementValidate : this.checkErrors.bind(this)});
        }
        this.errorSections = $H({});
    },
```

then

```
var loginForm = new VarienForm('loginForm', false);
```

`validator` is a variable `(see  this.validator  = new Validation..)` that store the validation instance.

```
function onepageLogin(button)
{
    //check to see if the validator instance exist and programmatically validate the form
    if(loginForm.validator && loginForm.validator.validate()){  
        //disable the button to prevent multiple click             
        button.disabled = true;
        //submit the form since all the required field are entered 
        loginForm.submit();
    }
}
```

See [Invoke validation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/72192/invoke-validation/72193#72193)

Comment: Very clear answer and good references. Is there a way that i can disable only password validation (while keeping the email validation intact) inside a form containing email and password

Comment: Remove the class name from password field

Comment: Thanks. i did exactly that. But on eventual submit, it still asks for the login and password. Is creating a dummy form and over-riding the only possible way around this

Comment: Turn on template hint or view page source to make sure you editing the correct file, all you need to do is remove the correct css classname